# Tmux refresh client call from fish shell alias

Tags: tmux, fish

I want `tmux` pane title to refresh immediately after I start `htop`, so I added alias in my `config.fish`:

```
alias h "htop;tmux refresh-client -S"
```

But it does nothing. I also tried with delay:

```
alias h "htop;sleep 0.1;tmux refresh-client -S"
```

That also did nothing - `tmux` still refreshes only after default interval, which is too long for me, and you can only decrease it to 1 second and not less.

What did I do wrong and is it even possible what I want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is a bit easier to see when we remove the `alias` from the equation:

```
echo banana; sleep 5s; echo sausage
```

will echo "banana", wait for 5 seconds and only then print "sausage", so

```
htop; tmux refresh-client -S
```

will run htop, wait until it is finished and *then* run `tmux refresh-client -S`, at which point fish will be the foreground process again.

---

What would have to be done instead is to get the shell to integrate with tmux. Now, apparently tmux has an escape sequence for [Names and titles](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#NAMES_AND_TITLES), so

```
printf '\ekhtop\e\\' # \e is \033 - the escape character
```

changes the window title to "htop".

Fish has events that functions can be bound to, so something like

```
function tmux_name --on-event fish_preexec
    printf '\ek%s\e\\' "$argv" # the argument for preexec is the commandline about to be executed
end
```

will set the tmux window name always to the command line. This won't reset it when the command has finished, so we need a second function

```
function tmux_reset_name --on-event fish_postexec
     # $argv for postexec is also the commandline
     # so we can't use it. Just hardcode "fish".
     printf '\ek%s\e\\' fish 
end
```

Not that this is perfect or anything - it'll still set the title even for very short-running commands, it'll use the full commandline even for long commands (maybe using just $argv[1] would be better).

Note that these functions will have to be defined in config.fish or a file explicitly sourced by it (or ~/.config/fish/conf.d/), because function files are autoloaded, so fish won't know about the event.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot! By the way, maybe that should added to tmux fish sources as default?

Comment: What tmux fish sources? There's the tmux project, which AFAIK doesn't do anything fish-specific, and then there's fish, which handles tmux-as-a-terminal, but nothing like this, which will replace the default tmux behavior with its own.